# Storing values enter by the user

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, cordova

I am fairly new to web development and HTML etc, I am currently developing an app using HTML,PHP and javascript and using PhoneGap to make it compatible with ios and android devices.

I need to allow the user to enter in a value into textboxes and then it will then carry out a calculation and the user can then go back and view these calculations once they close the app. My question is that is possible to store these calculations without having to set up a database and create users or will the user have to keep the app open at all times to keep these records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is all you want to do, it sounds like local storage will work just fine for you: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't give you enough details about your app to give you a specific answer to your question.

Nevertheless, 
-you might want to transfer the results to an external file and query sth. via your backend, 
-or start a reverse TCP connection from your app to your server.

I hope I could help.